# Should the regular iterator (or a similar range / view class) derive from const_iterator?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, iterator, const-iterator

Is it a good practice to make the regular iterator (or a similar range or view class) derive from the corresponding const_iterator?

The **motivation** for this is

- sharing the code, and
- avoiding conversions, when the iterator / view is big.

As an example, consider a view of a 3D grid, *i.e.* a section of the grid. It may contain 1 pointer, 3 sizes and 2-3 strides, for a total of 384 bytes.

The const and mutating versions would have a *lot* of common functionality (anything you can do with a read-only 3D grid).

The **anti-motivation** for the above example is that the const view contains a const pointer, and so the mutating view would have to do a `const_cast` to use it, or add an extra field containing the same address in a non-const pointer.

Comment: No, it makes the const_iterator a (mutating) iterator

Comment: If anything the relationship should be the opposite..., every operation you can do with a `const_iterator` is a valid operation on a `iterator`, but not the other way around.  Then again, I would not use inheritance by default for iterators, I may *abuse* it if the complexity of the iterator code makes the hack worth it, but I would avoid it [probably move the implementation to a third type and share the code in both `iterator` and `const_iterator`]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  Thanks, I reversed the inheritance relationship in my question. I hope this is not a breach of SO etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is inheritance between const_iterator and iterator it should probably go the other way.  That is a const iterator provides the basic ability to navigate and the mutable iterator adds the ability to modify the target (implemented by allowing protected access to const_iterator internals).

Edit: the original question asked about deriving const_iterator from iterator.  That is a bad idea as both I and @David Rodriguez pointed out at almost exactly the same time.

With the revised question, deriving iterator from const_iterator, David's comment provides the best response.   It can be done but it's usually not a good idea.

As a counter-question: what advantage do you see in using inheritance for this case?   If there is an advantage, does having a common base class (iterator_impl) from which both iterator and const_iterator are derived provide the same advantage?

Comment: Thanks! I reversed the inheritance relationship in my question. I hope this is not a breach of SO etiquette.

Comment: It is confusing because the two comments and the answer you have received so far are based on your original question.